# What does jQuery event.relatedTarget do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't quite understand what this does

I read the rather official short documentation on it

https://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/

> Description: The other DOM element involved in the event, if any.
>
> For mouseout, indicates the element being entered; for mouseover, indicates the element being exited.

I looked at the w3schools example on it

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_relatedtarget

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div, p").mouseenter(function(event){
        $("#msg").html("Related target is: " + event.relatedTarget.nodeName);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="height:200px;border:solid">This is a div element 
  <p style="background-color:pink">This is a paragraph</p>
</div><br>

<div id="msg" />

</body>
</html>
```

If you specify `mouseenter` as the event, does `relatedTarget` show the current container its in?

But what if you had jQuery event handler with both a "mouseleave" and "mouseenter" at same time?

could someone elaborate what the use cases are for event.related target as well in the real world if any?